# Java: как отлаживать jar, запущенный на удаленной машине?

Tags: java, maven

Ситуация: есть удаленная машина (`Virtualbox` + `Vagrant`), на ней крутится всякое `php`. На ней же запущено два `standalone`-приложения, написанные на `Java`, запускаются они через `java -jar ...`. Есть желание несколько поправить работу двух данных приложений, для этого скачаны их репозитории, установлена `IntellJ IDEA (CE)`, получается даже пересобирать исправленные исходники через `Maven` (не влезая в дебри, просто запуская `Run Maven Build`).

Но это крайне неудобно, так как приходится каждый раз собирать заново, закидывать все это на удаленный сервер, там потом смотреть логи приложения, и тд. Хочется какой-то интерактивной отладки, когда кодовая база правится наживую, ну или все-таки билдится в некий jar, и потом при обращении к приложению мы можем интерактивно просматривать что оно делает.

Поэтому вопрос: как отлаживать удаленно запущенные `java`-приложения, запакованные или не запакованные в `jar` при помощи `Maven`, на локальной машине, имеющей в арсенале `IntellJ IDEA (CE)` и Windows на борту?

Уточнение: обращение к данному софту происходит по неким веб-интерфейсам, то есть всякое упомянутое выше `php` лезет на условно `127.0.0.1:1234`, отправляет туда некий запрос и после этого активизируется наш софт на `Java`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускаешь jar с отладочными параметрами

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=192.168.0.100:8888,server=y,suspend=n -jar someapp.jar
```

И цепляешься отладчиком на указанный адрес

```
jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=192.168.0.100,port=8888 -sourcepath src\main\java
```

[Здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/attaching-to-local-process.html) описано как сделать это в отладчики IDEA.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Я верно понимаю, что можно где угодно запустить софт, главное потом порт пробросить, если потребуется?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете.

Comment: Ничего дополнительного при таких параметрах запуска не потребуется устанавливать? Может быть, править в софте самом? Я совершенно не настоящий java-программист, если что.

Comment: Внимательнее посмотрел ссылку на документацию jetbrains, там речь идет о присоединении к процессу локальному, тогда как у меня он удаленный. Как быть? Я не вижу возможности в описанном по ссылке функционале использовать вашу вторую строку.

Comment: Впрочем, нашел сам: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html

Comment: В общем отладка заработала и стала показывать где сейчас что выполняется. Поэтому вам однозначно спасибо, но есть еще вторая часть вопроса - обязательно ли каждый раз пересобирать jar и выкатывать его на удаленную машину, может быть есть какой-то способ побыстрее это все реализовывать?

Comment: А пересобирать придётся. Горячая замена кода в Java возможна только при использовании специальных агентов, типа [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

Comment: Понял, еще раз спасибо. И это очень печально )